# How to keep 2 Ladda Buttons in-synch

Tags: javascript, ladda

I have a requirement to place the same button on both the top & bottom on the screen.  I have just discovered Ladda & would like to find a way to keep these 2 Ladda Button states in-sync.  I have a few ideas on how to do it, but most are pretty ugly.

**Q:** How can I keep the run-state of 2 Ladda Buttons in-sync?

[image]

**HTML:**
Both buttons have the same markup.

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-next ladda-button ladda-button-success" data-style="expand-left">
    <span class="ladda-label">Next</span>
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
    <span class="ladda-spinner"></span>
</button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT EVENT:**

```
btnNext: function (e) {

    var action = that.settings.actions.next;
    var l = Ladda.create(this);
    l.start(); // <-- How can I "force" a start across multiple buttons?

    // Do other stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has a more eloquent answer I will definitely mark THEIRS as correct, but this is what works for me...

- User the same HTML (as-above)
- Setup the LADDA EVENT (see the Initialize function in the PageController)
- Setup a call for each DOM ELEMENT button (see the btnNext function in the PageController)

**PAGE CONTROLLER:** 
I'm going to just paste the entire controller. Ladda doesnt seem to understand jQuery-objects.  So, I had to go this route.

```
var PageController = (function ($, Ladda) {

            function PageController(options) {
                var that = this,
                    empty = {},
                    dictionary = {
                        elements: { form: null, btnNext: null },
                        selectors: { form: 'form', btnNext: '.btn-next'}
                    };

                var initialize = function (options) {
                    that.settings = $.extend(empty, $.isPlainObject(options) ? options : empty);

                    // Elements
                    dictionary.elements.form = $(dictionary.selectors.form);
                    dictionary.elements.btnNext = $(dictionary.selectors.btnNext, dictionary.elements.form);

                    // Events
                    dictionary.elements.btnNext.on('click', that.on.click.btnNext);

                    Ladda.bind(dictionary.elements.btnNext);
                };

                this.settings = null;
                this.on = {
                    click: {
                        btnNext: function (e) {

                            // Notice I had to point to the actual DOM ELEMENT for each button    
                            var action = that.settings.actions.next;
                            var topLadda = Ladda.create(dictionary.elements.btnNext[0]);
                            var bottomLadda = Ladda.create(dictionary.elements.btnNext[1]);
                            topLadda.start();
                            bottomLadda.start();

                            dictionary.elements.form.attr('action', action);
                            dictionary.elements.form.submit();
                        }
                    }
                };

                initialize(options);
            }

            return PageController;
        })(jQuery, Ladda);
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me to activate the spinner on all the page's Ladda buttons simultaneously using a jQuery selector:

```
// Create a new instance of ladda for the specified button
var btns = $('.ladda-button').ladda();

// Start loading
btns.ladda('start');

// Stop loading
btns.ladda('stop');
```